# Лицензирование ПО на Java

Tags: java, лицензирование

Здравствуйте! Скажите пожалуйста нужно ли лицензировать приложение написанное на Java? Например есть программа состоящая из двух частей клиентской и серверной. Как их лицензировать? Приложение коммерческое т.е. за пользование взимается плата.

Comment: Странный вопрос. Если вам нужно лицензировать свою разработку, лицензируйте. Как минимум для этого надо обеспечить обязательное ознакомление пользователя с текстом лицензии.

Comment: Я с 1С работаю, так что не странный:) Если я напишу программу на 1С то для запуска в клиент-серверном варианте мне нужно оплатить лицензию на использование сервера и дополнительно оплачивать каждого подключенного клиента хоть он из браузера подключился хоть с тонкого клиента. Как в Oracle с Java обстоят дела не знаю. Как Oracle зарабатывает на Java?

Comment: На что придется раскошелиться если часть функционала перенести на Java?

Comment: В 1С лицензии вы оплачиваете на использование проприетарной платформы. Java-программы самостоятельны и платформы не требуют. JVM - это открытое ПО. И даже если серверной части вашего приложения нужен сервер приложений, есть и они опенсорсные.

Comment: На программистов.